# Llenar listview

Tags: android, android-studio, arraylist, android-listview, arrayadapter

Estoy intentando llenar un `listview` desde un `arralylist` pero me genera un error y cierra la aplicación:

```
devices.get(0)=Cannot find local variable 'devices'
```

Si comento la linea `listView.setAdapter(adapter);` y hago un `debug` en `arrayListDevice.add(device.getName());` puedo observar como los valores se almacenan sin problemas los datos en el `arraylist`.

Y esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
package com.traceroute.kitkat;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.particle.android.sdk.cloud.ParticleCloudException;
import io.particle.android.sdk.cloud.ParticleCloudSDK;
import io.particle.android.sdk.cloud.ParticleDevice;

public class DeviceSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    int cantidad=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_selection);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.lvDeviceList);


        final ArrayList<String> arrayListDevice = new ArrayList<>();

  final ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayListDevice);



        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override

            public void run() {

                try {

                    List<ParticleDevice> devices = ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().getDevices();

                    for (ParticleDevice device : devices) {


                        arrayListDevice.add(device.getName());


                    }

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {


                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dispositivos...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
 listView.setAdapter(adapter);


                } catch (ParticleCloudException e) {
                    e.getBestMessage();
                }

            }
        });

        t.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrías compartir el error que te está mostrando? De lo contrario, se hace difícil poder ayudarte.

Comment: devices.get(0)=Cannot find local variable 'devices'

esto lo vi corriendo el debug

Comment: todo ocurre cuando intento llenar el listview, si comento la linea 
"  listView.setAdapter(adapter);"
y hago un debug en " arrayListDevice.add(device.getName());"

puedo observar como los valores se almacenan sin problemas los datos en el arraylist.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Mike, te sugiero revisar en el LogCat y agregar el mensaje de error especifico que se muestra, ya aseguraste que ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().getDevices() obtiene en realidad datos?.  No olvides realizar el [tour] saludos!

Comment: si he comprobado que ParticleCloudSDK.getCloud().getDevices()  obtiene datos

Answer (score 0):

ahora obtengo este error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-6
                  Process: com.traceroute.kitkat, PID: 26922
                  android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:7406)
                      at android.view.ViewRootImpl.focusableViewAvailable(ViewRootImpl.java:3473)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:848)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:848)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:848)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:848)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:848)
                      at android.view.ViewGroup.focusableViewAvailable(ViewGroup.java:848)
                      at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:13352)
                      at android.view.View.setFocusableInTouchMode(View.java:9531)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.checkFocus(AdapterView.java:752)
                      at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:576)
                      at com.traceroute.kitkat.DeviceSelection$1.run(DeviceSelection.java:84)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/AbstractTracker: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
D/OSTracker: OS Event: crash
E/AbstractTracker: mTrackerAsyncQueryHandler is null